# Backfill values after splitting one column in table

Tags: google-sheets

I have the left side of [this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WtK0I.png), but need the right side. What are the formulas for columns D and E?

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).
See [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `split()` and the concatenation operator, like this:

```
=arrayformula( 
  query( 
    split( 
      flatten( A2:A & "→" & split(B2:B, ", ", true, true) ), 
      "→" 
    ), 
    "where Col2 is not null", 0 
  ) 
)
```